# How to disable the rename option from everywhere (i.e, from file menu & context menu) in eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I am developing a plug-in which is basically create a new project, project contains more than one folder, and the folder contains our own customized editors. Now I dont want to allow the user to rename of the project from anywhere. I can see the rename option in file menu, context menu of project explorer, context menu of package explorer, context menu of navigator. Is it possible to disable/customize the rename option globally. I have tried to use global action handler for rename action,which is basically doing my own job whenever the rename action occurs. But since I want to block/disable the rename option at the time plug-in activator get started, I am able get active view site on the activator class, which doesn't seems to help me because of the active view might be anyother than above mentioned view at sometimes. Hence I tried to using 'Rename Participant' through ltk's renameparticipant extension and I wrote my own class which extending RenameParticipant, but the class never get initiated even I have given the correct class name in plug-in.xml file.

Since our product is plug-in

Could anyone please advise me that how should I proceed further? I hope that someone has already walk on this path to block the rename option globally.

Comment: Could you explain what problems renaming would cause? Perhaps those issues can be overcome by other means. Because, frankly, trying to block user from renaming a (physically existing) folder is doomed to fail.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My plug-in project is basically for transfering the xml files into server system (not to DB). The user inputs has been build as xml and on a particular event occurence, I will send the xml file to the server system using FTP/SFTP  protocol. The current issue is, if the user renaming a project after that project's xml file sent to server, then the server contain a xml file with old project name, which I couldn't find back to eclipse means my plug-in provides ability to read project related xml file from server system also.

Comment: ... I have tried to resend the xml file on the occurence of renaming using IResourceChangeListener, which leads me uncertainity. If the protocol fails/ server connection is unavailable then the renaming occurence can't transfer the files to server. The IResourceChange event doesn't allow us to block the rename after it initiated. Hence I'm not able to block the rename operation if the server connection unavailable. Then only I intended to disable the project renamaing ability from everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify your own handler to global rename (*id="org.eclipse.ui.edit.rename"*) and Java Rename element (*id="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.rename.element"*) commands using [`Handlers`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/extension-points/org_eclipse_ui_handlers.html) extension point. However, it is not possible to disable the context menu item (Refactor > Rename...) in Package Explorer because it is hard-coded.

Comment: Many Thanks for your response. And I'm able to customize the rename option now. But this is only work with 'Rename' option from 'File' menu. The custom renameHandler doesn't work with cotext menu of 'Project Explorer', and 'Navigator' view. Does this handler not enough for getting hook on context menu? Is there any other way to block the rename option from context menu. Kindly suggest me. And I'm sure I will think around alternative way instead of blocking rename. Since I need to complete this soon, I'm looking upon a simple way... Once again thanks for your help

Comment: @Bharath I originally didn't notice that you had already tried to set handlers. Updated my answer.

Comment: <extension     
       point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
  <handler class="com.example.plugin.RenameHandler" commandId="org.eclipse.jdt.ui.edit.text.java.rename.element">
     <activeWhen>
        <iterate>
           <and>
              <instanceof
                    value="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject">
              </instanceof>
              <test                    property="org.eclipse.core.resources.projectNature"                   value="com.example.plugin.natures.ExampleNature">
            </test>
         </and>
       </iterate>
    </activeWhen>
 </handler>  
</extension>

Comment: Many thanks. But still I'm unable to customize the context menu renaming. I have added my plug-in.xml entry above. I can customize the global renaming i.e through file menu. But eventhough I've added the above entry into my plug-in.xml file, the respective class never getting invoked. The global renaming customization still works fine. Am I have done anything wrong? kindly clarify me. Many thanks again.

Comment: @Bharath Well, like I said, unfortunately it is not possible to change the context menu item, it is added to the menu by Package Explorer code that you can't change (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/eclipse.org/3.4.2/org.eclipse.jdt/ui/3.4.2/org/eclipse/jdt/internal/ui/packageview/PackageExplorerPart.java#857).

Comment: @ Vanaprogeja. I'm glad to say that the context menu rename entry also being customized using command id="org.eclipse.ltk.ui.refactoring.commands.renameResource" which is work perfectly with ProjectExplorer and Navigator but not with Package Explorer. And You are the amazing person, really you helped much to me. Eventhough Thanks is just the word, I'm really meaning for it to you now. All credits regarding this topic dedicated to you. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I removed from context menu using that class

```
public class MoveActionProvider extends RefactorActionProvider  {

    //@Override
    public void fillContextMenu(IMenuManager menu) {}   

}
```

and declaring this into the plugin.xml

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.navigatorContent">
            <actionProvider
                    class="com.totvs.tds.ordinechaos.providers.action.MoveActionProvider"
                    id="com.totvs.tds.ordinechaos.providers.action.MoveActionExtension"
                    overrides="org.eclipse.ui.navigator.resources.actions.RefactorActions"
                    priority="highest">
                <enablement>
                <!-- A hack to allways be enabled -->
                    <not>
                        <systemTest
                                property="MyApp"
                                value="WONT-EVER-BE-SET">
                        </systemTest>
                    </not>
                </enablement>
            </actionProvider>
        </extension>
```